# How do I refine the y axis on a normal distribution plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

My Matlab function is close to doing what I want. It takes a vector of grades and generates statistics including a normal distribution plot. The problem is that the y axis doesn't seem to reflect the frequency of students that receive that grade.

[Image of normal distribution plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjVQY.png)

I've looked around on stack overflow for anyone experiencing my problem. I haven't been able to find anything.

```
function [M,m,ave,med,dev,v1]=GradeStatistics
% This program accepts grades and gives the maximum, minimum,average(mean), 
% median, standard deviation and also sorts the grades for the user. 
% This program was written by Jacob
clc;clear;close all;format compact;help GradeStatistics;
disp('Enter a vector containing all grades using square brackets')
v=input('Please give me the grades=');
M=max(v);m=min(v);ave=mean(v);med=median(v);dev=std(v);
v1=sort(v);H={'max';'min';'mean';'median';'std'};
G={M;m;ave;med;dev};clc;disp(table(H,G));
All={'max',M;'min',m;'mean',ave;'median',med;'std',dev};
xlswrite('mygrades.xlsx',All);VV1={'sort',v1};
xlswrite('mygrades.xlsx',VV1,1,'A6');
xlswrite('mygrades.xlsx',v1,1,'B6')

disp('Would you like to see a normal distribution?')
Case = input('Enter Y for yes or N for No=','s');
if lower(Case)=='y'
    f=(1/(dev*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((v1-ave)/dev).^2);
    hold on;plot(v1,f);title('Normal Distribution of Grades')
    xlabel('Score');ylabel('Students')
elseif lower(Case)=='n'
    disp('Thank you for using GradeStatistics')
end
```

Can anyone show me how to obtain a y axis that more accurately reflects the grade vector? Also let me know if there is anything else I should know to improve this function.

Example grade vector: [0 10 20 23 25 30 35 45 50 53 55 56 58 60 62 65 68 73 74 75 78 80 83 85 90 93 95 98 100]

Comment: Hi FlacOrGtfo! Welcome to Stack Overflow.

What exactly is wrong with the Y axis you're getting? Are the limits too big? Too small? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Hi yes, here is an image: https://i.imgur.com/IR2N27B.png I would expect larger values on the y axis. Those values look too small.

Comment: Stack Overflow tip: you can include an image inline in your main post by editing it and dragging & dropping the image file into the edit area. Makes it easier for people to read; they don't have to click through a second link.

Comment: Yep, those look pretty small. `plot()` usually gets the values right, so maybe there's something going on with that `f=(1/(dev*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((v1-ave)/dev).^2);` expression. Can you tell me a bit more about what that is computing? And do you expect the Y axis to go up to something like 1.0 (for the total proportion of grades) or more like 5 or 10 (for the absolute number of grades)?

Comment: I expect numbers more like 5 to be at the top of the y axis. And then it would be more like 1 at the bottom of the y axis.

Comment: Maybe you want a histogram, then? See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code Tweaking

Okay. First let's clean up this code a little bit.

```
clc;clear;close all;format compact;help GradeStatistics;
```

Don't do most of that. `clear` is never necessary at the beginning of a function: all functions automatically start out with a fresh workspace. `clc` and `format compact` should be left for the user to do: you don't know what their display preferences are. And leave `help` for the user to call when they need it. Also, avoid `close all`: you don't know whether the user has some figures sitting around that they wanted to keep!

And there's no need to call `hold` unless you are doing multiple plots into the same axes, which you aren't here. So remove that `hold on` call`.

Next, let's reformat the code a bit. Put each statement on a single line. This makes it more readable, and easier to debug with the Matlab debugger, since the debugger sets breakpoints and operates basically a line at a time. And let's stick in a few spaces between tokens for readability.

```
function [M,m,ave,med,dev,v1] = GradeStatistics
% This program accepts grades and gives the maximum, minimum,average(mean), 
% median, standard deviation and also sorts the grades for the user. 
% This program was written by Jacob
disp('Enter a vector containing all grades using square brackets')
v=input('Please give me the grades=');
M=max(v);
m=min(v);
ave=mean(v);
med=median(v);
dev=std(v);
v1=sort(v);
H={'max'; 'min'; 'mean'; 'median'; 'std'};
G={M; m; ave; med; dev};
disp(table(H, G));
All={'max',M; 'min',m; 'mean',ave; 'median',med; 'std',dev};
xlswrite('mygrades.xlsx', All);
VV1={'sort', v1};
xlswrite('mygrades.xlsx', VV1, 1, 'A6');
xlswrite('mygrades.xlsx', v1, 1, 'B6');

disp('Would you like to see a normal distribution?')
Case = input('Enter Y for yes or N for No=','s');
if lower(Case) == 'y'
    f=(1/(dev*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-0.5*((v1-ave)/dev).^2);
    plot(v1, f);
    title('Normal Distribution of Grades')
    xlabel('Score');
    ylabel('Students')
elseif lower(Case) == 'n'
    disp('Thank you for using GradeStatistics');
end
```

### Fixing the plot

I'm not sure what you're asking, because you're not saying exactly what's wrong with the Y axis/Y values you're getting. But since you say you want the Y axis "to reflect the frequency of students that receive that grade", it sounds like maybe you want a histogram plot instead of a line plot? The `plot()` function produces a line plot.

```
% Display Histogram
figure
histogram(v, 10);
title('Distribution of grades');
```

[image: GradeStatistics histogram example]

Comment: Yeah a histogram may be better. I got my function to display the above histogram. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You're welcome! How about giving me an upvote and an Accept if this solved your problem?

Comment: Good answer. My only suggestion would be to add conversion of y-axis to integer-ticks only since data is counts.